# Find two controls at once in visual studio 2015 IDE in a document

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to find two controls say Control1 and Control2 in a document in VS2015 IDE. I have tried MultilineFind/Replace and it doesn't seem to work. The only way I can find those controls are by pressing `Ctrl+F` individually in the document. Is there anyway I can highlight those two controls at once in document.

Comment: One option would be to [use a regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression as `Control[1-2]`.

When you press `Ctrl+F` there is a button in the search box for "Use regular expressions".

UPDATE: To match exactly only Control1 and Control2 and not DifferentControl2798, you can either switch on "Find whole words only" or use the regex `\bControl[1-2]\b`. The part `\b` stands for word boundaries. For more information on regular expression see the [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) as posted by stuartd.

UPDATE (after you posted real Control names): Regex `\b(m_gridItem|m_gdShipment)\b` should work fine.

Comment: I tried that but it is selecting more than those 2 controls

Comment: @Coder221 You don't give enough details... I assume it also finds Control13 and DifferentControl2789. Maybe you should think about other variable names for your Controls :) To match only Control1 and Control2 with the above regex, simply use "Find whole words only" in the search box (I'm not sure if this is the correct English label, since I'm using a German Visual Studio 2013).

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I was going through that link but nothing seems to work for me. Actually the control names are m_gridItem and m_gdShipment.

Comment: So how about `\b(m_gridItem|m_gdShipment)\b` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped.